# Is that built in allowed?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

I have recently created a coding language called [Valyrio](https://github.com/JaqueIsBaque/Valyrio). I have also posted a proposal for a question in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges). I have a problem though. It has been well-established that any builtin or language created after the code-golf has been posted is not allowed and any answer after this is non-competing. However, I added a builtin to Valyrio after I posted the Sandbox proposal that can do this challenge. The question, as of yet, has not been posted as a code-golf problem. Does this mean I can use the built in to complete the challenge or does it violate the non-competing rule?

Comment: [There is a loophole for that](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5772/62574). I think it depends on how much your answer relies on the built in. If your answer becomes boring or unfair because of the built in, I wouldn't include it. But if it's still a nontrivial solution, I think it should be fine.

Comment: The question is the first one if ordered by active. The built in is the symbol `ß`. It is easiest to explain if you read the Stack Commands doc on the GitHub repository.

Comment: @JackBates The loophole is about creating a builtin with prior knowledge of a challenge. As you knew about the challenge before adding the builtin, it is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I wasn't sure if it violated the rules.

Comment: Considering that it's your challenge, you may not wish to answer it anyway, as it could discourage others from answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It depends

(But based on what I've seen of your built in, probably not)

There is a [loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5772) for creating/modifying a language while it's in the sandbox. [Dennis' comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/5772#comment17314_5772) gives 2 main reasons why this is not allowed: It's unfair and boring.

Here's where the ambiguity comes in. If your built in makes your answer boring, you probably shouldn't post it (or you could include it in another answer of the same language, If you felt the need). If your built in makes your answer unfair (but not uninteresting!), you may want to post it as it's own answer, but noncompeting.

Or you could just leave it out, especially if your answer would only be a few bytes.

From (briefly) reading the documentation, It looks like your answer would be very short due to the built in. In that case, I would not post it, as it most likely falls under both categories.

**The bottom line is, If your answer is nontrivial and interesting, then go for it. Otherwise, just let it pass.**

Comment: Thanks. This really cleared it up!